# Can't reference XSSF in Apache POI 3.5 .jar

Tags: java, excel, apache, netbeans, apache-poi

I am trying to use `XSSFWorksheet` in the Apache POI 3.5.

I am using JDK1.7 and Netbeans 8.0.2. I have added copied all the .JAR files to a library file and added the library in Netbeans. The XSSF classes don't show up in the binary. I can see the HSSF classes but not XSSF.

Strangely the imports recognise `org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook` and `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook` but not `org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook`.

I do see the class source code in the .poi.usermodel but not the binary. I also can't see the class in poi-ooxml and the schema jar file. What .jar file is it in? What exact libraries do I need to run XSSFWorksheet and XSSFSheet? I notice that there is Maven support but not for Netbeans.

Answer (score 2):

The class `XSSFWorkbook` is contained in the poi-ooxml jar-file, as [detailed in the Apache POI components documentation](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components), so if you add that to the classpath correctly it should become available.

Please also try to update to the latest version poi-3.13 or even poi.3.14beta1, which have a huge number of [fixes since 3.5](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html#3.5-final), added features and other vital improvements to support newer features of the Microsoft formats.

Comment: Thanks @centic. I successfully used import for XSSF. Strangely a link to poi-ooxml .jar in Netbeans did not resolve it.  I used poi-3.13 and individually linked in each binary .jar file rather than use classpath to point to the poi-3.13 folder as a library.  I may persist and see if I can use Classpath as it will make future updates easier to manager for compilation.

Comment: Specifying a path usually does not load any .jar file that are located there automatically, it just loads resources like .class files that are located there, but not any "sub" jars, only specifying the jar directly will load it into the classpath.